# Uncaught Error: Container Is Not Defined - Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to load a google chart and am getting the following answer:

Uncaught Error: Container is not defined

I've read the other questions about this message for Google charts and the most common problem seems to be if getElementById isn't working correctly.

However, I don't believe this is the issue for me, or at least not an issue in the same way it is for others.

This is the Google Charts code I have:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['gauge']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["Label", "Value"],
            ["Match", state.greens[0].score]
        ]);

        var options = {
            redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
            yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90,
            minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById("chart-div"));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        setInterval(function() {
            data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            }, 13000);
};
```

This is almost point blank what Google has in their Gauge chart reference: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

I'm literally just trying to use the most straightforward example from their docs to generate a chart with my data.

Here's the html I have:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="chart-div">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have the javascript in a separate file, and load the api in the head of my html file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean the script is not reading the bootstrap css correctly?

Comment: I see.  Yes, does use a bootstrap container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("chart-div")` looks for an element with an *id* set to `chart-div`.  Your div is using the *class* attribute instead of the *id* attribute.  Change `<div class="chart-div"></div>` to `<div id="chart-div"></div>`

Alternatively, you can do `document.getElementsByClassName('chart-div')[0]`, where *0* is the ordinal of the element you want.  This way may be preferred, since you could post multiple charts on a page; but note getElementsByClassName is not supported in older browsers (pre IE-9)

Comment: is using .getElementsByClassName('chart-div')[0] the only way to load multiple charts on the same page?  If so, that's lame.  I recieved the same 'Uncaught Error' when calling google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarChart) and google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGaugeChart) on the same page using getElementById even though each had their own unique ids.  Doing it your way worked, but seems googlecharts should offer the standard approach too.

Comment: Ok, NM, I found a problem I was not aware of - using this notation for a div <div id="pieChart"/> <div id="guageChart"/> as mentioned in the google doc examples does not work.  You must use <div>...</div> then you can load multiple containers.  FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the previous answer. You can still keep it a class but do:

```
document.querySelector(".chart-div");
```

---

Or if you want to have more support:

```
var elems = document.layers || document.all || document.getElementsByTagName("*");
//          Netscape           < IE 6          All Other
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    if (elems[i].className === 'chart-div') {
        // Do something with those elements
    }
}
```

I think this supports as back down as Netscape 5 but don't hold me on that.

Comment: Nice fallback.  Are you sure `document.layers` gets all elements?  I can't remember, but I thought it worked like a mixture of z-index and frames.  Perhaps if no `<layer />` element is used, it finds all elements?

Comment: @vol7ron I'm not sure either `document.layers` would all all elements or it held all `layer` (Netscape `div` equivalent) tags. I originally learned HTML and JavaScript from a old book *(1996, 1998? I'm not sure)* which never even mentioned `div`s. If someone happens to be using Netscape, most websites will look weird a visualization won't be much of a problem

Comment: That must have been a relatively old book.  *div* and *span* were the elements that really drilled home the concept of *inline* vs *block* displays   and helped people transition form table-based layouts.  They also helped bring about the improvements we've seen in CSS.